# Notify friends of a user who starts using your facebook app

Tags: php, android, facebook, notifications, facebook-sdk-3.0

I realize this is a bit vague, but I have no idea where to even begin searching for this. I know for a fact that when a user registers on "Circle" using facebook they somehow have found a way to notify all of that users facebook friends that they joined Circle or at the very least it notify all of a users friends who also registered with circle that they joined. How did they accomplish this using the Facebook SDK?

One more time to be perfectly clear:  Currently when one of my friends registers with the social app "Circle" using facebook I end up getting a notification on Facebook telling me  "Joe Smith joined Circle" and I would like to know how to get my app to do the same thing using the fb sdk

Comment: That’s done by simply reading your friend list when you sign up, compare the Facebook ids of your friends with their database, and then sending a notification to those that they find in their database …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A circle is normally known as a "group", and is just implemented by three tables: a `user` table and a `group` table, plus a many:many table inbetween them. By convention this is called `user_group`, and usually just contains two columns - `user_id` and `group_id`. The combination of those two columns is usually defined as a primary or unique key, to ensure a user cannot join a group twice.

Joining a group involves inserting a row into the last table, and leaving a group just requires deleting a row from the same. To delete a group entirely, you need to delete all of its memberships, and to delete a user, you need to remove them from every group they belong to.

For this sort of work, it helps to create foreign key constraints, to enforce referential integrity.

Comment: I've answered in the general case, but wonder now whether "circles" in a Facebook sense are stored on the FB side? If so, that would be purely an API issue, since it involves no local database work. However, you can certainly do this stuff on the local side, with each `user` being a FB user. Can you clarify?

Comment: in talking about the app "circle" bro lol, not a circle of friends or a google+ circle. If you dont know what im talking about google "circle app"

Comment: Right, no idea I'm afraid. Good luck with it!